# RapidMiner - Generate Association rules for each date

Tags: rapidminer, market-basket-analysis, fpgrowth

I'm trying to find out association rules in my Market Basket Analysis by applying FP-Growth.
My concern is to find association rules by Date, means finding out item associations on daily basis for up to a year.
I can design to get associations for couple of days but it's time consuming to design it for 356 days. Dataset is as follows. 
[image]

I have used the Market basket analysis template given in Rapidminer.
[image]

How can I achieve this by couple of step rather than executing for each day up to a year?

Thanks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><process version="9.0.002">
  <context>
    <input/>
    <output/>
    <macros/>
  </context>
  <operator activated="true" class="process" compatibility="9.0.002" expanded="true" name="Process" origin="GENERATED_TEMPLATE">
    <process expanded="true">
      <operator activated="true" class="retrieve" compatibility="9.0.002" expanded="true" height="68" name="Retrieve Clustered Data with Items" width="90" x="45" y="187">
        <parameter key="repository_entry" value="Clustered Data with Items"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="filter_examples" compatibility="9.0.002" expanded="true" height="103" name="Filter Examples" width="90" x="313" y="187">
        <list key="filters_list">
          <parameter key="filters_entry_key" value="ReceiptDate.eq.01/05/2017"/>
        </list>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="aggregate" compatibility="6.0.006" expanded="true" height="82" name="Aggregate" origin="GENERATED_TEMPLATE" width="90" x="112" y="336">
        <list key="aggregation_attributes">
          <parameter key="Orders" value="sum"/>
        </list>
        <parameter key="group_by_attributes" value="Invoice|product 1"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="pivot" compatibility="9.0.002" expanded="true" height="82" name="Pivot" origin="GENERATED_TEMPLATE" width="90" x="246" y="336">
        <parameter key="group_attribute" value="Invoice"/>
        <parameter key="index_attribute" value="product 1"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="rename_by_replacing" compatibility="9.0.002" expanded="true" height="82" name="Rename by Replacing" origin="GENERATED_TEMPLATE" width="90" x="380" y="336">
        <parameter key="attribute" value="Invoice"/>
        <parameter key="replace_what" value="sum\(Orders\)_"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="replace_missing_values" compatibility="9.0.002" expanded="true" height="103" name="Replace Missing Values" origin="GENERATED_TEMPLATE" width="90" x="112" y="442">
        <parameter key="default" value="zero"/>
        <list key="columns"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="numerical_to_binominal" compatibility="6.0.003" expanded="true" height="82" name="Numerical to Binominal" origin="GENERATED_TEMPLATE" width="90" x="246" y="442"/>
      <operator activated="true" class="set_role" compatibility="9.0.002" expanded="true" height="82" name="Set Role" origin="GENERATED_TEMPLATE" width="90" x="380" y="442">
        <parameter key="attribute_name" value="Invoice"/>
        <parameter key="target_role" value="id"/>
        <list key="set_additional_roles"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="concurrency:fp_growth" compatibility="9.0.002" expanded="true" height="82" name="FP-Growth" origin="GENERATED_TEMPLATE" width="90" x="648" y="289">
        <parameter key="positive_value" value="true"/>
        <parameter key="min_support" value="0.005"/>
        <parameter key="find_min_number_of_itemsets" value="false"/>
        <enumeration key="must_contain_list"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="create_association_rules" compatibility="9.0.002" expanded="true" height="82" name="Create Association Rules" origin="GENERATED_TEMPLATE" width="90" x="648" y="442">
        <parameter key="min_confidence" value="0.1"/>
      </operator>
      <connect from_op="Retrieve Clustered Data with Items" from_port="output" to_op="Filter Examples" to_port="example set input"/>
      <connect from_op="Filter Examples" from_port="example set output" to_op="Aggregate" to_port="example set input"/>
      <connect from_op="Aggregate" from_port="example set output" to_op="Pivot" to_port="example set input"/>
      <connect from_op="Pivot" from_port="example set output" to_op="Rename by Replacing" to_port="example set input"/>
      <connect from_op="Rename by Replacing" from_port="example set output" to_op="Replace Missing Values" to_port="example set input"/>
      <connect from_op="Replace Missing Values" from_port="example set output" to_op="Numerical to Binominal" to_port="example set input"/>
      <connect from_op="Numerical to Binominal" from_port="example set output" to_op="Set Role" to_port="example set input"/>
      <connect from_op="Set Role" from_port="example set output" to_op="FP-Growth" to_port="example set"/>
      <connect from_op="FP-Growth" from_port="frequent sets" to_op="Create Association Rules" to_port="item sets"/>
      <connect from_op="Create Association Rules" from_port="rules" to_port="result 1"/>
      <connect from_op="Create Association Rules" from_port="item sets" to_port="result 2"/>
      <portSpacing port="source_input 1" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 1" spacing="147"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 2" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 3" spacing="42"/>
      <description align="left" color="yellow" colored="false" height="70" resized="false" width="850" x="20" y="25">MARKET BASKET ANALYSIS&lt;br&gt;Model associations between products by determining sets of items frequently purchased together and building association rules to derive recommendations.</description>
      <description align="left" color="blue" colored="true" height="185" resized="true" width="550" x="20" y="105">Step 1:&lt;br/&gt;Load transaction data containing a transaction id, a product id and a quantifier. The data denotes how many times a certain product has been purchased as part of a transactions.</description>
      <description align="left" color="purple" colored="true" height="341" resized="true" width="549" x="20" y="300">&lt;br&gt; &lt;br&gt; &lt;br&gt; &lt;br&gt; &lt;br&gt; &lt;br&gt; &lt;br&gt; &lt;br&gt; &lt;br&gt; &lt;br&gt; &lt;br&gt; &lt;br&gt; &lt;br&gt; Step 2:&lt;br&gt;Edit, transform &amp;amp; load (ETL) - Aggregate transaction data to account for multiple occurrences of the same product in a transaction. Pivot the data so that each transaction is represented by a row. Transform purchase amounts to binary &amp;quot;product purchased yes/no &amp;quot; indicators.&lt;br&gt;</description>
      <description align="left" color="green" colored="true" height="310" resized="true" width="290" x="580" y="105">Step 3:&lt;br/&gt;Using FP-Growth, determine frequent item sets. A frequent item sets denotes that the items (products) in the set have been purchased together frequently, i.e. in a certain ratio of transactions. This ratio is given by the support of the item set.</description>
      <description align="left" color="green" colored="true" height="215" resized="true" width="286" x="579" y="425">&lt;br&gt; &lt;br&gt; &lt;br&gt; &lt;br&gt; &lt;br&gt; &lt;br&gt; Step 4:&lt;br/&gt;Create association rules which can be used for product recommendations depending on the confidences of the rules.&lt;br&gt;</description>
      <description align="left" color="yellow" colored="false" height="35" resized="true" width="849" x="20" y="655">Outputs: association rules, frequent item set&lt;br&gt;</description>
    </process>
  </operator>
</process>
```

[Sample Data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SqClpfrgEi6i97L8LheyHKbCD8l-9piPuc5pwE5qTlg/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Can you post the XML of the process and perhaps a sample of the data as well?

Answer (score 0):

After retrieving your data as an example set, you can then use the `Loop Values` operator to loop over the `ReceiptDate` attribute. The current value (in your case, the date) is stored in the `loop_value` macro.

You then put the whole process of building your association rules inside the subprocess and change your `Filter Examples` operator to condition class `expression` with `ReceiptDate==%{loop_value}` as the parameter expression.

This will filter your whole dataset, so you only keep examples of the current date, then build your model on that subset. As a result, you get a collection of different models on the out-port of `Loop Values`.

If you frequently build different models based on one (or more) parameter, it might be interesting to have a look at the [Jackhammer](https://marketplace.rapidminer.com/UpdateServer/faces/product_details.xhtml?productId=rmx_toolkit) extension by [Old World Computing](https://oldworldcomputing.com/en/jackhammer-extension/) - the `Indexed Model` operator does exactly this for you (build specific models for different parameter values). It makes using these specific models a no-brainer, since you get one single model that you can then apply on your data - the model matching the parameters is automatically selected and applied.

Comment: thnx for reply. I will check your approach.